# Google Sheets countif attendance sheet, quarterly report

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a Google Sheet that I use to track attendance at an open lab that I run. Each quarter I put together a report where I count the number of people that attended that quarter. If I just use the count function I could include people that only attended the first quarter in the second quarter report or that attended the second in the third.

I want a way to say, "*if this person attended between these dates then count them*."
For example, in the picture I attached `Name 2` only attended during the first quarter so they wouldn't be included in the second quarter count. `Name 5` attended during both so they would be included in both counts.

My best idea for putting this into Google Sheets is 
`=countif(A2:A29,B2:Y2<>0)`
or in other words count the names if they attended during the first quarter. Is there any way to do this?

Edit: Here's a link for the spreadsheet:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SwukY3SsjWfYyu2RakED0S0V4kZwRfNN0nVoDsKMN5A/edit?usp=sharing

Doing this manually there should be 38 people that attended during the first quarter and 42 that attended the second.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a sample where I tried to solve the issue in tab "Result"](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f13fiXPKHID0Al4QEWGs03unbzmGiIj8U7Zd2FZfCZY/edit?usp=sharing)

There's some additionnal columns for each quarter (`A:A, B:B, C:C`) then with some QUERY you can check if there has been an attendance or nah.

The formula in `A3` :

`=index(transpose(query({transpose(INDIRECT(A2))},"Select "&textjoin(",",TRUE,ArrayFormula(if(len($D$3:$D$100),"Max(Col"&ROW($D$2:$D$100)-ROW($D$2)+1&")","")))&"")),,2)`

There is a main query with the range `A2` for the first quarter: in this cell you can add the desired range, you can try a formula to automate this. (I.E. filter every date with the desired months ('=MONTH') then take the reference of the cells containing `MAX' and 'MIN' values)

The query select the max value of every row (the range has been transposed). 
You can also use dynamic range for the `LEN` and `ROW` formulas.

Then it just `=TRANSPOSE` the data. `=INDEX` is way to pick the second column (first column is fill with names)

You can now go to tab `Clean` for a simple `=IF` formula checking wether or not attendees where present during quarter/period 1

Edit : [Credit for 3/4 of the formula](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/find-max-value-in-each-row-in-google-sheets/)